# Json schema with anyOf fields to POJO

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I wonder what's the recommended way to generate POJOs for Json schemas with "anyOf" fields?

For example, given the following json schemas:

hobby.json

```
{
    "anyOf": [
        { "type": {"$ref": "./exercise.json" } },
        { "type": {"$ref": "./music.json" } }
    ]    
}
```

exercise.json

```
{
    "type": "object"
    "properties" {
        "hobbyType": {"type": "string"}
        "exerciseName": { "type": "string" },
        "timeSpent": { "type": "number" },
        "place": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

music.json

```
{
    "type": "object"
    "properties" {
        "hobbyType": {"type": "string"}
        "instrument": { "type": "string" },
        "timeSpent": { "type": "number" }
    }
}
```

How could I generate a POJO for `Hobby.java` with Jackson?

Comment: Use map inside map, that might help

Comment: In case of anyOf shouldn't there been an discriminator, too?

Comment: @SvenDöring Is discriminator supported by Json Schema? I thought it's an openApi spec. Could you share a doc regarding this and may I know in which version of Json Schema this is supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking is using polymorphic marshaling/unmarshaling functionality provided by Jackson.

Specifically -

1. Make `hobby` to be an interface and annotate it with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    property = "hobbyType",
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = Exercise.class, name = "exercise"),
        @Type(value = Music.class, name = "music")
})
public interface Hobby {
}
```

2. Create `Exercise.java` and `Music.java` that implements this interface

```java
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Exercise implements Hobby {
    @JsonProperty("hobbyType")
    @Builder.Default
    @NonNull
    private final String hobbyType = "exercise";    

    @JsonProperty("exerciseName")
    private String exerciseName;

    @JsonProperty("place")
    private String place;
    //... (other fields)
}
```

3. Use `Hobby` for serialization and deserialization.

```
// create a Hobby object
Hobby exercise = Exercise.builder().exerciseName("swimming").place("swimmingPool").build();

// serialization
String serializedHobby = new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(exercise)
/**
serializedHobby looks like this ->
{
    "hobbyType": "exercise",
    "exerciseName": "swimming",
    "place": "swimmingPool"
}
*/

// deserialization
Hobby deserializedObject = new ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Hobby.class)
// deserializedObject.getClass() would return Exercise.java or Music.java based on the hobbyType
```

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: What would your classes look like if it was "oneOf" or "allOf" instead of "anyOf"?

Comment: @aeberhart I think it depends on the structure of the schema. If it needs to deserialize/serialize in a polymorphic way, you can perhaps try this approach.

Comment: Ok makes sense. So I guess your question is more about polymorphism rather than the differences between allOf, anyOf, oneOf, correct?

Comment: I guess you could say that. The way `anyOf` is used in my case is best to be resolved with polymorphic marshaling/unmarshaling

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two approaches that seem natural:

One would be to generate a class hierarchy Hobby with the common field timeSpent and Music / Exercise being subclasses with their specific fields.

The other would be to "union" the fields into a single class Hobby.

Both are semantically incorrect meaning that you can come up with cases where JSON schema validates correctly but Jackson throws an error or the information is missing in the POJO due to an omitted field.

So I think the best approach here would be to resort to Map<String, Object> instead of pojos.

So for example if a Person has a hobby the Person POJO could be:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  ...
  Map<String, Object> hobby;
```

or List<Map<String, Object> hobbies> if one can have multiple hobbies.